# How to push automatically from live server to bitbucket when update WP theme and plugin?

Tags: wordpress, git, shell, github, bitbucket

I have used Bitbucket and develop a website in WordPress/PHP. Whenever I'm updating theme and plugin to latest version from wp-admin. Code not pushed to Bitbucket Repository(There is no log for newest file over bitbucket).

Is there any automatic way to push updates/latest file to Bitbucket?

I pulled file from Bitbucket Use Bitbucket hooks like in this post, but not commit or push data. 
http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/ 
any more idea about this hook, please help.

**// Shell Scripting**

I have used shell scripting, to run git commands on live server and created a file **"gitCommit.sh"** and put where is .git folder is located(repository).

Set a crontab to run this file.

- - - - - sh /var/www/html/wp-pusher-infinite/gitCommit.sh

file name **gitCommit.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
git add --all
git commit -m "Auto update files"
git push origin --all
```